# Magento : Zero Grandtotal Paypal Checkout Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express, grand-total, reward-points

I used Magento1.9.2.4, When I add product and apply promo code and also spend reward points that will made my grandtotal amount $0, and on checkout I select paypal.
The issue is that paypal not accept $0 grandtotal checkout.

Kindly Suggest how can I fix this?

Comment: if Grand total is zero then why you want to go with paypal ? 
You may enable zero sub total checkout payment method in magneto 
Or explain if you are looking for any other  change

Comment: Yes, I try but that time it is not showing in payment method list on frontend, I tried after reindex and clean cache it is working. But on my live site we are using only payment method that is paypal. Can we do the same with paypal?

Comment: But if grand total is zero then what paypal will charge you ? 
then why we need to go to paypal ?